# How to a string into a mutable array and store the previous string when entering another

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

The goal for this project is to let user enter two separate string and be able to concat together. In the console, you can see all concat history users entered.

For example, 1st time, user entered "app" and "le", and clicked button "combine" then console stored "apple".

Then, user entered "123" and "45", then in the console it should show that user entered "apple" and "12345".

My problem is now, I couldn't store any user input in my mutable array.

I appreciate it if someone can help!

Here's my code:

```
import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myString1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myString2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *combinedString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayhere;
@property int arrayCount;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *userInput1 = self.myString1.text;
    NSString *userInput2 = self.myString2.text;
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", userInput1, userInput2];
    self.combinedString.text = result;
    [self.arrayhere insertObject:result atIndex:self.arrayCount];
    self.arrayCount++;
    NSLog(@"list of portmanteaus is %@ ", self.arrayhere);
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize `self.arrayhere`?

Comment: BTW - why do you have a separate `arrayCount` property? `NSMutableArray` already has a `count` property.

Comment: I didn't realize NSMutableArray already has this. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you viewDidLoad: you need to add:

```
self.arrayhere = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then in your buttonPressed action, you need to replace:

```
[self.arrayhere insertObject:result atIndex:self.arrayCount];
```

with:

```
[self.arrayhere addObject:result];
```

This will automatically add that object to the end of your array, no need to have a property for the count of the array, as @rmaddy stated it is already a property of NSMutableArray.

Therefore, you can also remove this line:

```
self.arrayCount++;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it a lot! Go Spartan (if I assume you from there)!

Comment: The 1st line should be `self.arrayhere = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
 import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myString1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myString2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *combinedString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayhere;
@property int arrayCount;

- ( void )viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  arrayhere = [NSMutableArray new];

}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
     NSString *userInput1 = self.myString1.text;
     NSString *userInput2 = self.myString2.text;
     NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", userInput1, userInput2];
    [arrayhere addObject:result];
     NSLog(@"list of portmanteaus is %@ ", self.arrayhere);
}
```

Comment: 1) Code only answers are frowned upon here. Provide some details about what was wrong and what your answer fixes. 2) Your solution is incorrect. In `viewDidLoad` it should be `self.arrayhere = ...` or `_arrayhere = ...`.